# How to use this CustomSort function to sort listview?

Tags: delphi, callback

If customsort function is passed in with a variable, it seems it will access violation.

```
public 
...
col: integer;
...

Procedure listviewcol;
begin
  col:=5
...
end;

procedure TForm1.sortcol(listview: tlistview);
  function CustomSortProc(Item1,Item2: TListItem;
    OptionalParam: integer): integer;stdcall;
  begin
    Result := AnsiCompareText(Item2.subitems.Strings[col], Item1.subitems.Strings[col]);
  end;
begin
  ListView.CustomSort(@CustomSortProc,0);
end;
```

This will prompt errors. // access violation

But if we change col in AnsicompareText to 5, it works well.

```
procedure TForm1.sortcol(listview: tlistview);
  function CustomSortProc(Item1,Item2: TListItem;
    OptionalParam: integer): integer;stdcall;
  begin
    Result := AnsiCompareText(Item2.subitems.Strings[5], Item1.subitems.Strings[5]);// it works.
  end;
begin
  ListView.CustomSort(@CustomSortProc,0);
end;
```

How to fix it. 
Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: could you please edit your question and make it more readable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access `col` inside the callback function, it is not a method of your form. Your trick of nesting the callback in a method is futile. ;) If you need to access form fields then use the `OptionalParam` to be able to refer to your form in the callback.

```
begin
  ListView.CustomSort(@CustomSortProc, Integer(Self));
  [...]

function CustomSortProc(Item1,Item2: TListItem;
  OptionalParam: integer): integer; stdcall;
var
  Form: TForm1;
begin
  Form := TForm1(OptionalParam);
  Result := AnsiCompareText(Item2.subitems.Strings[Form.col],
      Item1.subitems.Strings[Form.col]);
```

Of course you can send the value of `col` in 'OptionalParam' if that's the only thing you need. Or, you can make 'col' a global variable instead of a field, or use the 'Form1' global variable itself which the IDE puts just before the implementation section if it's not commented out.

You can also make use of the [OnCompare](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomListView_OnCompare.html) event.

Answer (score 2):

Pass col as OptionalParam:

```
function CustomSortProc(Item1,Item2: TListItem; col: integer): integer;stdcall;
begin
  Result := AnsiCompareText(Item2.subitems.Strings[col], Item1.subitems.Strings[col]);
end;

begin
  ListView.CustomSort(@CustomSortProc, col);
end;
```

Or use Sertac answer - he was faster :)